# I want to automate a scenario in which multiple products needs to be asserted with respect to filter values from a ecommerce website?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I want to automate a scenario in which multiple products needs to be asserted with respect to filter values from a ecommerce website. I want to know what could be the approach which we can implement using selenium?

Comment: can u provide what you have done so far

Comment: Yes. please find below the framework structurisation that I have thought of, i am not sure though whether it is correct or not but just and abstract way,

Comment: if you have some better way to deal with this situation, then pls let me know or comment here..thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi plz try like below

```
public class ComparingItems {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Multiple products
        String mProducts[] = {"Reebok","addidas","puma"};
        // filter values from e commerce website
         String eProducts[] = {"Reebok","Fila","puma"};

         // now how to assert the two use below logic
         for(int i=0;i< mProducts.length;i++){
             Assert.assertEquals(mProducts[i], eProducts[i], "Item Not matched");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Rajnish, that could be used as a core code in my framework.

Comment: m glad that it helped you

Comment: its not complete though still the problem of designing the framework is still not solved but that snippet could be utilised somewhere in the picture..so just keeping it for future reference. thanks

Comment: ok i give the above snippet talking in mind that if u have multiple products and e products already in comparable mode

Comment: yeah i got that Rajnish..the problem is to decide how and what all packages to be defined to reach the stage where your snippet can be used. :) might be i need to try Page Object Modelling. lets see..i will keep posting.

Comment: yeah sure i will be very glad if i can help u further

Answer (score 0):

```
**RegressionTestSuite** 
@test
1)filter1
@test
2)filter2
@test
3)filter3
@test
4)filter1 and filter2
@test
5)filter1 and filter3
@test
6)filter2 and filter3

*CommonOperations class* //abstract class
void selectCategories(String variable){}
void setFilterCriteria(filter1, filter2, filter3){}
void hoverProduct(){}
void clickAndViewDetails() {}  

// there could be many more methods which are common to finding product details across the website.

FilterTypeMobile interface
{void getMobileDetails(){}
filter variable common to mobile phones
}

                class TelevisionProduct implements FilterTypeTelevision
                {@overridden
                void getTelevisionDetails(){}
                }


FilterTypeTelevision interface
{void getTelevisionDetails(){}
filter variable common to Televisions
}

                class MobileProduct implements FilterTypeMobile
                {@overridden
                void getMobileDetails(){}
                }
```

I have basically written basic framework without implementation. Right now I am just deciding on the strategy to achieve automation.

Comment: can anyone suggest, is this the right way to build automation framework for an e-commerce website? I am trying to develop the framework from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a framework for same, here are a few best practices which I follow:

1. Make good use of Test Execution frameworks. I use TestNG.
2. I create a base file which makes use of most of the TestNG annotations for Setting and Tearing up.
3. Separate your Re-usable functions and call it wherever needed. I generally add these in the base class.
4. I personally prefer keeping locators too in the base file if they are too complicated. This would help you to change the locator from one place and get reflected for all. In this case, do follow a good naming convention.
5. Use collections wherever possible.
6. You can use something like ReportNG for more user friendly reports.
7. Make more use of implicit waits and avoid using JavascriptExecutors.
8. Copy the Drivers and libraries within the project folders for better mobility and less external dependencies.
9. Adding selenium WD javadoc to your project will be of some help.
10. We also make sure we have a screenshot for failed test case by over-riding the `onTestFailure` method.
11. Rest all are simple coding basics for cleaner and easy to understand code that I believe you'll be following anyway.

Also, this may not be the best place to post such query as per regulations of this forum. But still I believe my answer is of some help.

Comment: Prateek, thank you for the help. But, actually I have gone though good number of blogs on automation and including topics like Design pattern implementation like facade, page object modelling, adapter, decorator and few more. but here being a novice I am unable to decide which will be right approach. So just keeping in mind OOPs design principles, I am trying something which is achievable and easy to maintain. Suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Yes I understand that as I said and I hope my suggestions helped. :)